# Couldn't make POST request from iPhone to ColdFusion API

Tags: iphone, post, coldfusion, httprequest

I am having a strange problem while making an application in iPhone. The problem is in making a POST request to the server API in ColdFusion. We have two servers: one is for Testing and other for Production. The app works perfectly on the Testing server, but when we do a POST request in Production server the API couldn't read the request variable and gives error as `Element xxxxx is undefined in ATTRIBUTES`, but actually it is there. One reason could be different User-Agents, but after trying many combinations it does not work.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You say "actually it is there" but how do you know for sure?  It sounds like you need to debug using `<cfsavecontent>` and `<cfdump var="#attributes#">`, so you can check if the variables are going where you expect.  This debugging method is explained here: http://blog.alagad.com/2010/04/05/debugging-using-cfsavecontent-and-cfdump/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was the "LINK" I was using. The API worked with adding "www" to the link, where as I was using the link without "www". Hope it helps someone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're talking about different user-agent? It's iPhone to test server or iPhone to production server, no? Is the configuration exactly the same including the Application.cfc (or Application.cfm)?

Web app or native app calling cfc's?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think user-agents make any difference. Try to submit request directly through browser to make sure it is really working. Best way to do that NSLog url request and paste it in browser.

Comment: it works from the web browser, but doesn't work when I submit through iPhone, though it works on other server. PS:- Only POST doesn't work, GET works fine.